# Error simbolo externo sin resolver. c++

Tags: c++

El codigo del programa:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MemLoadLibrary.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef void(_cdecl* func)();


int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CLoad lib;
    HANDLE hLibrary = lib.LoadFromFile("vana.dll");
    func fn = (func)lib.GetProcAddressFromMemory(hLibrary, "TestFunc");
    fn();
    lib.FreeLibraryFromMemory(hLibrary);
    return 0;
}
```

El error es el siguiente

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void * __thiscall
>   CLoad::LoadFromFile(char const *)" (?LoadFromFile@CLoad@@QAEPAXPBD@Z)
>   referenced in function _main

Mi pregunta es porque este error o alguna sugerencia para resolverlo?

Comment: El enlazador se queja de que no encuentra una función. Eso es porque usas librerías externas, y no has indicado que ciertos símbolos son externos. Eso se hacía con los archivos .lib, pero varia de un entorno a otro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te viene a decir que el *linker* no es capaz de encontrar la librería.

Mira las opciones de compilación ya que has de indicar dónde se encuentra la librería precompilada (.dll en el caso de las librerías dinámicas o .a / .lib en el caso de librerías estáticas)

En el caso de gcc y similares la sintaxis a indicar suele ser algo tal que:

```
gcc -l[libreria_dinamica] fichero.c -l[libreria_estatica]
```

Como por ejemplo:

```
gcc fichero.c -lMemLoadLibrary.a
```